# Qt 5.1.0 build problems with ui_*.h files

Tags: forms, qt, compiler-construction, build, makefile

I have one problem with building my Qt project(`v5.1.0`).

If I change a form(for instance `ui_<formname>.h`), I have to manually copy it.

**From:**

`<QT Path>\workspace\build-<Project name>-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug`

**to**

`<QT Path>\workspace\<Project name>`

Otherwise, I have still the old form. I think I have some errors in the `MakeFile`'s, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with creating a new Qt project with the same name. (Before I backuped the old one to the Desktop). Afterwards I added all my classes(`*.h`, `*.cpp` and `*.ui`) to the directory workspace folder. In Qt Creator right click on the project and `Add Existing Files`. Then you have to overrite the `main.cpp`, `mainwindow.h`, `mainwindow.cpp` and `mainwindow.ui`. In `<Qt>/workspace/<Name>` are no more `ui_*.h` files and now they get updated automatically.